# writing a trigger in order to change Table Name automatically

Tags: sql-server

Imagine there are two databases named "DB1" and "DB2".
There are two tables on both databases which are the same.
I mean we have "Table1" in "DB1" and also "Table1" in "DB2" and the data is the same as well.
I need to write a trigger so that whenever i change "Table1"'s name on "DB1", the name be changed automatically *by a trigger* on "DB2".
thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Any specific obstacles you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[Sys.Trigger_event_types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-trigger-event-types-transact-sql)</kbd> will have all the events that can be fired.

On checking, it has an event type called `RENAME`. You could use that write a DDL trigger, though this may not be ideal but serves your purpose.

```
alter trigger  tst
on database
for
RENAME 
as 
begin

declare @oldtblname sysname,@newtablename sysname
  SELECT 
       @oldtblname= EVENTDATA().value  
        ('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/Parameters/Param)[1]','nvarchar(max)') ;

          SELECT 
       @newtablename= EVENTDATA().value  
        ('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/Parameters/Param)[2]','nvarchar(max)') ;

exec otherdbname.dbo.sp_rename @oldtblname,@newtablename;

end
```

There are some catches, since this is database level scoped event, this will fire for all rename events, you may want to check event type and if it is only `<ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>`, then you may wish to continue.

**Note:**
I have  SQLServer 2012 and 2005 machines, this RENAME didn't worked on 2005 but worked on 2012. Not sure about 2008.